# Control MediaWiki generated html

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to control the html generated by the application. In other words: When an user saves an article the html article generated would have some aditional html tags. For example the first section of the article would be within a div, with a specific ID. BUt this shouldn't change the text when editing the article, only the "article view" panel would have that div. Was I clear enough?

Is there any extension that can help me?
If no, should I develop my own extension? If so can you give some advises about the flow? I never develop an extension, and any highlights and insights you can give would probably save lots of research time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article already has its own individual `div` when created.  It is how the `div#header`, `MediaWiki:(anon|site)notice`, `MediaWiki:Sidebar`, and the `div#content` are separated.. I would first suggest try using your browser's `View Source` feature on a few parsed pages to see what the output looks like.  `div#content` can be used in your skins or css to make adjustments to it accordingly..  I hope this helps, or prompts you for move information appropriately. :D